# iptables status enabled after restart even after disabling

Tags: linux, iptables

I am disabling iptables on Oracle Linux 6 with these commands.

```
setenforce 0
service iptables stop
service ip6tables stop
chkconfig—level 123456 iptables off
chkconfig—level 123456 ip6tables off
```

Even after doing this on reload when i do the

```
service iptables status
```

i see iptables as enabled and it loads up all the information from the file

```
/etc/sysconfig/iptables.save
```

but the strange thing is then if i use the command chkconfig i see the status as off for all run levels still the above command has enabled iptables.

```
chkconfig --list iptables
iptables        0:off   1:off   2:off   3:off   4:off   5:off   6:off
```

Let me know if you would have answer to any of these questions

Would it be ok to delete the iptables.save file completely.
How should i disable iptables service across reboots.
Is the network Manager causing iptables service to be started ? inspite of chkconfig saying its off still some service seems to be enabling it.

Answer (score 1):

I found your question on stack overflow, as I had the same problem. I just solved it and I might be able to help you:

I had installed the firewall CSF and completely disabled iptables. Yet iptables kept restarting for some reason. After a while I found that CSF restarted it after an ip-address (mine in this case) made too many connections. I was pinging the server from one ip address and after 3000 calls, or 5 minutes, the connection refused because iptables blocked my ip-address. I added the ip addresses to the "allow-list" of csf by using CSF -a 192.168.1.1  where 192.168.1.1 was my ip address...

Hope this helps you!

Comment: i checked up and i dont have any csf program installed neither anything similar to it.